# impression tracking for dynamic content

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, dynamic, content

I want to track the clicks and the sends done on the basis of the dynamic content used in the email. 
I have already got the impression tracking report activated but in the report not getting details on the dynamic content.

Do I need to do some setting in the emails also to get the reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you have named and added "Begin impression region" and "End impression region" amp script to the beginning and end of each block you wish to track.

I am not sure how you are creating your dynamic content blocks, but if you are creating them 'manually' this can be done quite easily with ampscript:

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/impression_tracking/impression_region_using_ampscript/

If you are using Content Builder to create your dynamic content this should be done automatically for you:

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/impression_tracking/impression_region_using_dynamic_content/

You can sometimes check this by looking at the plain text version of your email created by the content builder, you might be able to see the rules for dynamic content tracking in there:

Example:

```
{{#=if (([Attribute] == "Some Value"))}}
{{= BeginImpressionRegion("01__Rule_1__An_Image.png")}}{{= EndImpressionRegion()}}
{{.else}}
{{= BeginImpressionRegion("01__Default_Content__Other_image.png")}}{{= EndImpressionRegion()}}
{{/if}}
```